# How to match keys in a dictionary with the elements in a list and store those key values to another dictionary in python?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{'and': {'in': 0.12241083209661485,
         'of': 0.6520996477975429,
         'to': 0.7091938791256235},
 'in': {'and': 0.12241083209661485,
        'of': -0.46306801953487436,
        'to': -0.0654517869126785},
 'of': {'and': 0.6520996477975429,
        'in': -0.46306801953487436,
        'to': 0.8975056783377765},
 'to': {'and': 0.7091938791256235,
        'in': -0.0654517869126785,
        'of': 0.8975056783377765}}
```

and a list like this:

```
list1 = ['the', 'of', 'Starbcks', 'in', 'share', 'for', '%', 'fiscal', '2007',
         'growth', 'year', 'cents', 'earnings', 'a', 'company', '2,400', 'net',
         'abot', 'range', 'stores', 'revene', 'sales', 'gidance', '``', "''",
         'earnings', 'provides', 'wew', 'net']
```

I want to traverse through the list and check whichever words equals the keys in the list, and then add those key values into another dictionary.

Like from this example, I want this as my result:

```
new_dict = {'in': {'and': 0.12241083209661485,
                   'of': -0.46306801953487436,
                   'to': -0.0654517869126785},
            'of': {'and': 0.6520996477975429,
                   'in': -0.46306801953487436,
                   'to': 0.8975056783377765}}
```

I am doing something like this:

```
for elem in l:
    temp_dict = dict((key,value) for key,value in similarity_matrix.iteritems() if key == elem)
print temp_dict
```

But I getting `{}` as my result. What's wrong and how to fix it?

EDIT:

Now, I took this:

```
OrderedDict(for k in list1:
    if k in d:
        new_d[k] = d[k]
    else:
        new_d[k] = 0)
```

i.e., the keys that are not there, will get values 0 in new_d. But, is there any way to get the dictionary in the same order as there were words in list1?

Like the output should be:

```
new_d : {'the' : 0, 'of': {'and': 0.6520996477975429, 'in': -0.46306801953487436,'to': 0.8975056783377765}, 'Starbucks' : 0, ......}
```

Comment: match only to main key??? is found then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list1 = ['the', 'of', 'Starbcks', 'in', 'share', 'for', '%', 'fiscal', '2007', 'growth', 'year', 'cents', 'earnings', 'a', 'company', '2,400', 'net', 'abot', 'range', 'stores', 'revene', 'sales', 'gidance', '``', "''", 'earnings', 'provides', 'wew', 'net']
d={'and': {'of': 0.6520996477975429, 'in': 0.12241083209661485, 'to': 0.7091938791256235}, 'of': {'and': 0.6520996477975429, 'to': 0.8975056783377765, 'in': -0.46306801953487436}, 'in': {'and': 0.12241083209661485, 'of': -0.46306801953487436, 'to': -0.0654517869126785}, 'to': {'and': 0.7091938791256235, 'of': 0.8975056783377765, 'in': -0.0654517869126785}}
new_d ={}
for k in list1:
    if k in d:
        new_d[k] = d[k]
print(new_d)
{'of': {'and': 0.6520996477975429, 'to': 0.8975056783377765, 'in': -0.46306801953487436}, 'in': {'and': 0.12241083209661485, 'of': -0.46306801953487436, 'to': -0.0654517869126785}}
```

Or a dict comprehension:

```
new_d ={ k: d[k] for k in list1 if k in d}
```

checking if  a key is in a dict or a set is `O(1)`

Using your own code you could do the following which checks if the key is in your list:

```
temp_dict = dict((key,value) for key,value in d.iteritems() if key in set(list1))
```

To keep the order the items were added you need to use [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
new_d = OrderedDict(((k,d[k]) if k in d else (k,0) for k in list1 ))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I edited my question, there was one thing I missed asking. Could you have a look at that? Thanks.

Comment: @MarthaPears, added an ordereddict

Comment: That didn't quite solve my problem, because it doesn't add 0 to values of the words which are not in the dictionary, and then give them in the same order as the list.

Comment: just replace the code in your edit with an `OrderedDict`, make `new_d` an `orderedDict`, I edited the answer doing it in the comprehension

Comment: You mean: OrderedDict(for k in list1:
    if k in d:
        new_d[k] = d[k]
    else:
        new_d[k] = 0) ? Its giving me syntax error.

Comment: Invalid syntax. And it highlights for .

Comment: use the code I posted exactly as is if you want to use it in a comprehension, if you want a loop all you have to do is change `new_d` to an `ordereddict` in the code you already have

Answer (score 0):

using dict comprehension:

```
new_dict = { x:y for x,y in my_dict.items() if x in your_list }
```

output:

```
{'of': {'and': 0.6520996477975429, 'to': 0.8975056783377765, 'in': -0.46306801953487436}, 'in': {'and': 0.12241083209661485, 'of': -0.46306801953487436, 'to': -0.0654517869126785}}
```

you can sort like this:

```
{ x:y for x,y in sorted(new_dict.items(),key=lambda x:my_list.index(x[0])) }
```

Comment: I forgot to ask one thing, could you have a look at my question again? I edited it.

Comment: Yes I know there is something like OrderDict. But how to use it?

Comment: I didn't quite solve my problem. It's giving me the same result as it gave before. Check my edited question.